# jQuery .find() method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a twitter feed related project and using Tweetie-master jQuery plugins.

Link: https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet

But unfortunately jQuery .find() method not working at all. I tried a lot but could not find the error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#twitter_feed').twittie({
        dateFormat: '%b. %d, %Y',
        template: '{{avatar}} {{tweet}} {{screen_name}} {{date}}',
        count: 3
    });
    $("#twitter_feed ul").find("li:first").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
});
</script>
```

My project demo link: http://zinan.me/twitter/

Comment: Can you post your markup, and perhaps put that and your JS into an environment like http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: $("#twitter_feed ul").find("li:first").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"}); Works fine when run in the console of the provided link. The problem is when run after twittie plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because when the `$("#twitter_feed ul").find("li:first")` is executed, no tweet has been loaded, so no `li` exists. You should use a callback function, if I do understand twittie :

```
$('#twitter_feed').twittie({
    dateFormat: '%b. %d, %Y',
    template: '{{avatar}} {{tweet}} {{screen_name}} {{date}}',
    count: 3
}, function () {
    $("#twitter_feed ul").find("li:first").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
});
```

Comment: could you see my demo link and suggest me what i need to do ?

Comment: @user3535842 I updated my answer. According to the definition of `$.fn.twittie`, it should workd.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `twittie()` is async, so code is not waiting for response. Before twittie returns anything, code executes `find` and finds nothing. Look for `twittie()` callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

As @Holt pointed that the jquery code is executed before the div is populated. 
If you want to change only first li's style then you can do it using CSS also:

```
#twitter_feed ul li:first-child { color: #F00; border: 1px solid #F00;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work not tested it though but worth a try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#twitter_feed').twittie({
        dateFormat: '%b. %d, %Y',
        template: '{{avatar}} {{tweet}} {{screen_name}} {{date}}',
        count: 3
    }).promise().done(function(){
        $("#twitter_feed ul").find("li:first").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: According to the `tweetie.js` file on the link specified by the author, there is no such `promise` function for `twittie`. In fact `$.fn.twittie` does not return anything at all so you will get an error.

Comment: I did say not tested though, should work by removing the promise() part.

Comment: Won't work if you remove the promise() part because, as I already said, `$.fn.twittie` does not return any object on which you can call `done`, `promise`, or whatever you want, you will just call a function on something `undefined`.

Comment: OK, looking at the `$.fn.twittie` in depth you are correct and your snippet is the right answer too. +1